# Create a commit and a pull request from the master branch

Tags: git, github

I often create quick little bug fixes and commit directly to master. I know this is rather dangerous since it skips the review step.

Instead, I know I should first create a new branch, commit to that branch and create a pull request on Github. 
Is there a command that achieves what I want (commit to PR instead of directly to master)?

Comment: `git checkout -b <branch> && git commit && git push -u <remote> <branch>`?

Comment: I understand I could chain those commands together, but this seems like a fairly common use case and I was wondering if there was a command that would perform all this together - perhaps by creating a random branch name, pushing to the remote and also creating the PR?

Comment: None that I know of, but you could put it in a script (call the script `git-something` and you can run it with `git something`) or a shell function.